# How to Convert Dictionary<String, Object> to ArrayList in C# 3.5

Tags: c#, dictionary, arraylist

I am passing the Dictionary parameter from the Javascript and trying to convert that to an Array List.

Example:

```
public void AssignEmployees(Dictionary<String, Object> _params)
{
   ArrayList ArrayEx= null;
   ArrayEx= (ArrayList)_params["Assignments"];

   ArrayList ArrayEx1= null;
   ArrayEx1= (ArrayList)_params["balance"];
}
```

This is a brief example and I have added the conditions which check if "_params" contains "Assignments" or "balance" then move forward.

> However it returns an error of Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Collections.ArrayList'.

Here is the screenshot of an ideal data of this dictionary object.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the Dictionary and use the `.Add` method of the `ArrayList` to insert the object to the array list. Or else try `.AddRange` method with Linq. Following code will help you:

```
ArrayList ArrayEx = new ArrayList();
foreach (var item in _params)
{
    ArrayEx.Add(item.Value);
}

// or like this

ArrayEx.AddRange(_params.Select(x=>x.Value).ToList());
```

Keep in mind, you can use the two methods to an Instantiated object of ArrayList class, so don't forget to initialize `ArrayEx` with an instance.

Comment: @RaviVyas : Glad to hear, Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

.Net 2.0

`ArrayList ArrayEx = new ArrayList();`

`foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int, object> KeyVal in objdictionary)
{
    ArrayEx.Add((object)KeyVal.Value);
}`